# Microsoft VBScript Compilation Error. Code: 800a0400. Error: - Expected Statement

Tags: vbscript

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC8KE.png)

```
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Perform all the SCCM Client Actions
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  On Error Resume Next

  Set objCPAppletMgr = CreateObject("CPApplet.CPAppletMgr")
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
     msgbox "There is no SCCM Client installed on this system.",16,"SCCM Client Actions -- FAILED --"
     wscript.quit
  End if

  On Error Goto 0

' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Display the results
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Set arrClientActions = objCPAppletMgr.GetClientActions()
  For Each objClientAction In arrClientActions
      objClientAction.PerformAction
      strText = strText & " -- Action: '" & objClientAction.Name & "' has been initiated successfully. " & vbCrLf
  Next
  strText = strText & vbcrlf & "Script engine: " & wscript.FullName & vbcrlf
  msgbox strText,64,"SCCM Client Actions"

' ================================================================================================
' END SCRIPT
' ================================================================================================
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check that you have saved the file as plain text (e.g. use Notepad). And no BOM (signature)